# Работа resolve в promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Есть такой код, один аспект которого мне не понятен:

```js
    'use strict';
    
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("Промис завершился");
      console.log("Промис ждет, пока я появлюсь");
    });
    
    promise
      .then(
        result => console.log("Fulfilled: " + result), 
        error => console.log("Rejected: " + error) 
      );
```

Собственно, не понятно то, что алерт в функции-конструкторе вообще отрабатывает своё и появляется. И сразу же за ним (это прям вообще не понятно - почему за ним?) появляется "промис завершился".
Не понятно по какому принципу работает `resolve()`, то есть передается управление обработчику `.then`.
Я много раз видел, когда `resolve()` помещали конкретно внутрь обработчика  `onload` (для ajax запросов, например), который сам по себе говорит о завершенности выполнения вопроса. А получается, что `resolve()` можно запихнуть хоть с самого начала и код ниже всё равно отработает.
Да, конечно, в случае с ajax можно ожидать отклонение запроса сервером, поэтому нужно использовать `resolve()` в случае успеха, а `reject()` в случае ошибки.
Помогите разобраться.

Comment: В принципе-то, можно поставить `return` перед `resolve("Промис завершился");`, тогда ниже код не будет выполняться, а управление и разультат передастся обработчикам `.then`. Но хотелось бы объяснение тому, почему так происходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JS остановить функцию может только или `return`, ошибка или её конец.
[Почитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#.22Run-to-completion.22).

В ожидании используется некий асинхронный подход (иначе не вышло бы отлавливать асинхронные операции, Ваш КО): при разрешении обещания, коллбэк встаёт в очередь до завершения ожидающего кода в функции и только потом вызывается.

Если Вам этого не нужно, используйте `return`: `return resolve();`.

Answer (score 3):

Промис(обещание) сам по себе никого не ждёт.
Просто у вас есть возможность обрабатывать как синхронный, так и асинхронный код.
Созданный Promise исполняется **сразу же**, синхронно(на самом деле это зависит от реализации), а своих подписчиков(then) уведомляет на следующем такте event-loop.

Давайте рассмотрим его поведение на примере:

```js
'use strict';
    
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("Промис завершился");
      console.log("1. Promise created");
    });
    console.log('2. After creation');
    promise
      .then(
        result => console.log("3. Resolved: " + result),
        error => console.log("Rejected: " + error) 
      );
    console.log('2.5 функция в .then тем не менее будет вызвана позже');
```

Как видите, Promise при создании сразу(синхронно) запустил свой executor, но обработчик в then будет вызван на следующей итерации eventLoop.

---

Пример внутренней реализации(очень урезанной):

```js
function Thennable(executor) {
  let thenList = [];
  let state = 0; // 1 - resolved, 2 - rejected
  let value = null;
  // executor вызывается сразу же, синхронно
  executor(
    res => { 
      thenList.forEach(then => 
        // обработчики вызываются асинхронно.
        setTimeout(() => then[0](res)));
      state = 1;
      value = res;
    },
    error => { 
      thenList.forEach(then => 
        setTimeout(() => then[1](error))
      );
      state = 2;
      value = error;
    }
  );
  this.then = (onResolve, onReject) => {
    if (state == 0) {// ещё не обработано, добавим в очередь ожидающих
      thenList.push([onResolve, onReject]);
    } else if (state == 1) { // resolved
      onResolve(value);
    } else if (state == 2) { // rejected
      onReject(value);
    }
    // return new Thennable(...)
  };  
}

let p = new Thennable((ok, fail) => {
  ok('resolved');
  console.log('1 created');
});
console.log('2 after create');
p.then(res => console.log(3, res))
```

Comment: Думаю, чтобы если было навешано несколько обработчиков, они вызывались более-менее параллельно.

Answer (score 1):

`resolve()` обычная коллбэк функция, вызов который говорит промису перейти в выполненое состояние. `resolve()` не останавливает выполнение функции внутри промиса.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу цитату из [статьи](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85), что бы не ошибиться:

> Согласно стандарту, у объекта new Promise(executor) при создании есть
> четыре внутренних свойства:
>
> PromiseState – состояние, вначале «pending».
>
> PromiseResult – результат, при создании значения нет.
>
> PromiseFulfillReactions – список функций-обработчиков успешного выполнения.
>
> PromiseRejectReactions – список функций-обработчиков ошибки.
>
> Когда функция-executor вызывает reject или resolve, то PromiseState
> становится "resolved" или "rejected", а все функции-обработчики из
> соответствующего списка перемещаются в специальную системную очередь
> "PromiseJobs".
>
> Эта очередь автоматически выполняется, когда интерпретатору «нечего
> делать».

То есть `resolve` не сразу вызывает функцию, а ждет окончания `функции-executor`, которую передали при создании `promise-a`